# Block showing users of a specific role is only showing up for the administrator

Tags: 7, views, users

I have a view/block that is shown to all the users who have a specific role (RoleX, member and administrator), and I set the view to a specific page. Whenever I look at the page as an administrator, I can see the block and everything looks great. When I log in as a user with the role RoleX, as authenticated user, or as anonymous user, and I look at the page, the block doesn't appear. I thought that this only happened if I only checked off the administrator when you go to `configure block` and then `roles` yet I left all of the roles unchecked so the block would be visible to all.

Does anyone have any idea how I might go about solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that there is an access check somewhere that is failing. When logged in as user 1, it's impossible for a standard access check to fail, so this would be why you're seeing the block.

To solve this, try granting ALL permissions to RoleX (make sure you do not do this on a live site) and see if the block appears when you log in as the test user who has RoleX. If the block starts showing up, start disabling permissions a few at a time until you find which one is causing the issue.